# Real Analysis - Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a, b$ be reals and $f : (a, b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable. We also assume that there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such
that $f(c) = 0,$ and that, for any $x \in (a, b),$ $f '
(x) \neq 0.$ We deﬁne $g : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = x −
\frac{f(x)}{f '(x)}$ and we notice that $g(c) = c.$

(a) Explain why $g$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$ and has a continuous derivative. Show that $g'(c) = 0.$

(b) Deduce that there exists $δ_1 > 0$ such that, $I_1 := [c − δ_1, c + δ_1]$ is contained in $(a, b)$ and, for any $x \in I_1 \:\: \text{such that}\:\: |g'(x)| ≤ 1/2.$

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Part (b) specifically

Comment: Have you shown that $g$ has a continuous derivative and that $g'(c) = 0$?

Comment: yes, I have found that g'(x) = f(x)f''(x)/(f'(x))^2

Comment: Since $g'$ is continuous and $g'(c) = 0$, then by continuity there must be some interval around $c$ such that $|g'(x)-g'(c)| = |g'(x)| < {1 \over 2}$ for all $x$ in this interval.

Comment: I've been able to show that $g^\prime(x) = \frac{f(x) f^{\prime\prime}(x)}{{(f^\prime(x))}^2}$, I'm having trouble continuing this question into part (b).

Comment: That's what I just answered in the comment above?

Comment: I don't understand how you made the statement $<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: If a function $f$ is continuous at $y$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $y$ satisfies $|x-y| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. So, let $f=g'$, $\epsilon = {1 \over 2}$...

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you so much that helped heaps! Kudos to you!

Comment: Let's also drop the phrase "local convergence of Newton's method".